Can I use a bus card from another city on a Greyhound bus in Philadelphia?
I purchased a bus card in Hazleton PA. Id like to know if I can use it in Philadelphia on a bus or the Greyhound towards bus fare.

Are you talking about a Smart Card as described at https://www.ridehpt.com/fares ?

No. Different transit systems use their own transit cards. Being able to use one system’s card in a different system is the exception rather than the rule, and generally restricted to single metropolitan areas.
